# dynamically add new option in jquery chosen plugin where select multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, append

I am using choose master http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

**Example**

---

```
<select data-placeholder="Click to Select Role..." style="width:200px;"  id="geoRange" name="geoRange" class="chzn-select" tabindex="8" multiple>
<option value="1">England</option>
</select>
```

---

I am adding new option in this select

---

```
$('#geoRange').append( new Option('USA',2) );
```

---

It is not working

How can I add new option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After updating the select list, you apparently need to also notify Chosen that you did that.

```
$("#geoRange").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

I haven't used Chosen myself (using Select2 instead), but that's what the docs say. See http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
var select1 = document.getElementById("geoRange");
select1.options[select1.options.length] = new Option('USA', 2);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select data-placeholder="Click to Select Role..." style="width:200px;"  id="geoRange" name="geoRange" class="chzn-select" tabindex="8" multiple>
<option value="1">England</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="fnc()" value="click me" />
```

Comment: dear, simple is working , but when i use harvesthq.github.com/chosen it is not working .

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor: That's most likely because Chosen doesn't update itself when the underlying select element is updated. You should look at Chosen's docs and see if you can detach and reattach it. Alternatively, maybe Chosen has its own API for adding new items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#geoRange').append( new Option('USA',2) );
```

The following statement solve my problem

```
 $("#geoRange").trigger("liszt:updated");
```